# Python Code to printable string and vice-versa

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a solution in python where I can pass a dict of conditions to a function and have the results printed out like so:

```
input_conditions = {    1: (a2>b2) & (b2<c2) ,
                        2: (a2>b2) & (b2>c2) ,
                        3: (a2>b2) & (b2==c2)  }

def myfunc(conds):
    a2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    b2 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
    c2 = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
    for k,v in conds.items(): print(f'{k}.) {v}: {np.sum(conds[k])}')
    return

myfunc(input_conditions)
```

expected result:

```
1.) (a1>b1) & (b1<c1): 3
2.) (a1>b1) & (b1>c1): 0 
3.) (a1>b1) & (b1==c1): 1`
```

The above obviously doesn't work because (1) input_conditions reference a2,b2,c2 before they have been declared in myfunc, and (2) the print command will print the resulting array for each condition, and not the string of the condition itself.

I am currently using the following solution, which works:

```
def currentfunc():
    a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    b1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
    c1 = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
    conds = {   1: (a1>b1) & (b1<c1) ,
                2: (a1>b1) & (b1>c1) ,
                3: (a1>b1) & (b1==c1) }
    descr = {   1: '(a1>b1) & (b1<c1)' ,
                2: '(a1>b1) & (b1>c1)' ,
                3: '(a1>b1) & (b1==c1)' }
    for k,v in descr.items(): print(f'{k}.) {v}: {np.sum(conds[k])}')
    return
currentfunc()
```

result:

```
1.) (a1>b1) & (b1<c1): 3
2.) (a1>b1) & (b1>c1): 0 
3.) (a1>b1) & (b1==c1): 1`
```

But, again, I am wondering if it would be possible to (1) define the dict of conditions BEFORE  the arrays are declared and (2) print out each condition in the dict without having to manually copy-paste them into a dict of strings.

PS - this is my 1st time posting in SO, and I apologize for any editing mistakes in the question.

Comment: Your code isn't valid python

Comment: When you write `(a2>b2) & (b2<c2)` in the dictionary assignment, it evaluates that expression and stores the result in the dict. There's no way to get back the original text of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function can be used here if you are sure to evaluate your code and not a user input.

Note: The use of `eval` to a user input is risky.

You can check out [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/5987)

```
import numpy as np

descr = {   1: '(a1>b1) & (b1<c1)' ,
            2: '(a1>b1) & (b1>c1)' ,
            3: '(a1>b1) & (b1==c1)' }

def currentfunc():
    a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    b1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
    c1 = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])

    for k,v in descr.items(): print(f'{k}.) {v}: {np.sum(eval(descr[k]))}')

currentfunc()
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/5987